# Are all odd integers greater than $599$ of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

For $a \le 10^7$, the equation over integers $4a+1=x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$
has solutions.

> Q1 Is it true that all integers of the form $4a+1$
> are also of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$?

Heuristic argument:  primes of the form $4a+1$ are sums of two squares.
The probability that integer $m$ is prime of such form is about
$\frac{1}{2 \log(m)}$. Fix $z=z_0,t=t_0$ and let $m=4a+1-z_0^4-t_0^4$
and hope that $m$ is sum of two squares.

For odd numbers up to $10^7$, the largest number not of such form
is $599$.

> Q2 Is it true that for all $a>299, 2a+1=x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$
> has solution?

Comment: $599$, or $299$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I thought he meant $2 \cdot 299 +1 = 599 $

Comment: Closest thing I've found is Friedlander, John & Wooley, Trevor. (2012). On Waring's problem: two squares and three biquadrates. Mathematika. 60. 10.1112/S0025579313000089. We investigate sums of mixed powers involving two squares and three biquadrates. In particular, subject to the truth of the Generalised Riemann Hypothesis and the Elliott-Halberstam Conjecture, we show that all large natural numbers n with 8 not dividing n, n not congruent to 2 modulo 3, and n not congruent to 14 modulo 16, are the sum of 2 squares and 3 biquadrates.

Comment: Checked both questions up to $10^8$. Nothing to report.

Comment: What about even numbers?