# Is $16a+5$ always of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Working over the integers.

For $a$ up to $10^7$, $16a+5$ is always of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4$.

> Q1 Is $16a+5$ always of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4$?

Heuristic argument:

For prime $p=4b+1$, both of $p$ and $2p$ are sums of two
squares. Fix $z_0$ and set $m=16a+5-z_0^4$.
$m$ is sum of two squares with probability at least $\frac{1}{\log(m)}$.

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446469/are-all-odd-integers-greater-than-599-of-the-form-x2y2z4t4).

Comment: Verified to $10^8$.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Thanks. What CAS are you using? I am using sagemath.

Comment: Embarrassed to say - a primitive one line of awk: gawk -vL=100000000 'BEGIN {for(a=0; 2\*a\*a\*a\*a<L; a++) {a4=a\*a\*a\*a; for(b=0; 2\*b\*b<L-a4; b++) {b2=a4+b\*b; for(c=b; c\*c<L-b2; c++) m[c\*c+b2]=a;}} for(s in m) for(d=m[s]; d\*d\*d\*d<L-s; d++) if((d\*d\*d\*d+s) % 2==1) n[d\*d\*d\*d+s]=1; for(i=1; i<=L; i+=2) if(!(i in n)) print i;}'   this was for the other question. For this question just modify the loop in a to only try a=0.

Comment: For the other question it ran in less than 50m. For this one in about 13m.

Comment: Increasing L by a factor of 10 increases runtime by about a factor of 20, but with awk the memory usage is huge. Writing this in C would allow a much better performance.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch I don't understand awk, but your script will be very slow for a=2^100, right? In sagemath for sums of two squares I use the factorization.

Comment: Correct. 2^30 is already out of limit for me.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Does your gawk abort() on `gawk --bignum 'BEGIN { a = 2 ^ 2 ^41; print "a =", a }'`? I reported this libgmp bug last year.

Comment: You can use -M, but only if gawk is compiled +mpfr, which I do with macports. But keep in mind that arrays are very memory wasteful in awk.

Comment: running in C++  no arrays;  started at 4 seconds per million, now about 7 seconds. So, maybe two hours to 10^9

Comment: done up to:   1,233,234,581     Wed 10 May 2023 02:04:40 PM PDT
1231234581

Wed 10 May 2023 02:04:52 PM PDT
1232234581

Wed 10 May 2023 02:05:05 PM PDT
1233234581