# Is every even number greater than $44$ not divisible by $8$ of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Related to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446469/are-all-odd-integers-greater-than-599-of-the-form-x2y2z4t4),
where `Bogdan Grechuk` suggested this question.

> Q1 Is every even number greater than $44$ not divisible by $8$ of the form $x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$?

This holds up to $10^7$.

Positive answers to both questions will imply that all
integers greater than $599$ not divisible by $8$ will be of the form
$x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$.

In a [related question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446506/is-16a5-always-of-the-form-x2y2z4?noredirect=1#comment1153545_446506)
there were verifications in `gawk` and `C++`.

For large values of $n=x^2+y^2+z^4+t^4$ we suggest the following
approach.

Choose small integer $B$.

Fix $z=z_0,t=t_0$ and set $m=n-z_0^4-t_0^4$.
Try to trial factor $m$ up to bound $B$ (or try to factor it completely).
If you can factor it completely, check if it is sum
of two squares, i.e. it doesn't have factor congruent to $3$ modulo $4$
with odd exponent.
The probability that random $m$ is sum of two squares is at least
$\frac{3}{2\log(m)}$ unless there are congruence obstructions.

Comment: I think that you need to take $m=n-z_{0}^4-t_{0}^4$.

Comment: @MaciejUlas Thanks for spotting the typo, just edited.